# Position DIV at cursor but within viewable area

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm using the showDiv function below to display a DIV popup menu at the cursor position but I can't figure out how to tweak it so that the menu doesn't disappear off the bottom or right-hand edge of the viewable area, is it possible to compensate for this before displaying the DIV?

```
var posx;
var posy; 

function getMouse(e){ 
 posx = 0;
 posy = 0; 
 if (!e) var e = window.event; 
 if (e.pageX || e.pageY){ 
  posx = e.pageX;
  posy = e.pageY; 
 } 
 else if (e.clientX || e.clientY){ 
  posx = e.clientX;
  posy = e.clientY; 
 } 
} 

function showDiv(id){ 
 var obj = document.getElementById(id); 
 obj.style.left=posx+'px'; 
 obj.style.top=posy+'px'; 
 obj.style.display='block';
}

...

<body onMouseMove="getMouse(event)">
```

Comment: The function `showDiv` is accessing scoped variables from the `getMouse` function? Or are they defined at a higher scope?

Comment: Could you add working code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showDiv(id){ 
  var obj = document.getElementById(id),
    screenWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) - (obj.clientWidth || obj.offsetWidth),
    screenHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0) - (obj.clientHeight || obj.offsetHeight);

  obj.style.left = Math.min(posx, screenWidth) + 'px'; 
  obj.style.top = Math.min(posy, screenHeight) + 'px'; 
  obj.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't get this elegant code to work, in that the DIV still appears off the bottom of the screen. Is this because the webpage extends down off the bottom of the screen too?

Answer (score 0):

This should keep the div within the view-able area.

You just check to see if the width plus the position etc are more or less than the values of the view-able area.

We also add on the scroll left and scroll top values so our calculations don't mistakenly think it's visible; you can remove that if it's not needed in your case though.

```
function showDiv(id, posX, posY) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id),
      objWidth = obj.offsetWidth,
      objHeight = obj.offsetHeight,
      docX = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
      docY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      winWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
      winHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  posX += docX;
  posY += docY;

  if (posX < docX) {
    posX = docX;
  } else if (posX + objWidth > winWidth + docX) {
    posX = docX + (winWidth - objWidth);
  }

  if (posY < docY) {
    posY = docY;
  } else if (posY + objHeight > winHeight + docY) {
    posY = docY + (winHeight - objHeight);
  }

  obj.style.top = posY + 'px';
  obj.style.left = posX + 'px';
  obj.style.display = 'block';
}
```